# Access variable via get-Method not working outside class

Tags: c++, class, get, set

My problem is, that if I print the Energy value of a field within the set-method of the specific field, it'll be printed, but if I try to print it right after exiting the set-method (code line 2 or 3) it always has the value of zero.

With the set-method `void Field::_dEnergy(double dEnergy)` I want to assign a value to `dEnergy` of `vvoField[][]`.

```
this->_vvoField()[uiY][uiX]._dEnergy(dCurrentEnergy);
std::cout << this->_vvoField()[uiY][uiX].dEnergy;
std::cout << "Energy: " << this->_vvoField()[uiY][uiX]._dEnergy();
```

My get-/set-methods look like this:

```
void Field::_dEnergy(double dEnergy)       { this->dEnergy = dEnergy; std::cout << this->dEnergy; };
double Field::_dEnergy()                   { return this->dEnergy; };
```

(For testing purposes I've set everything to public. Both get and set and the actual variable `dEnergy` within `Field`.)

Do I make anything wrong with the Brackets to specify the field or what's my problem here? If I print the energy of every field, none is set different than zero, so I guess the get is always giving 0.

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you even add a vector<Field> Object and add a Field-Object to your vector _vvoField?
(does _vvoField()[uiY][uiX] exist?)

Comment: Yes, every field also has an X and a Y position and if I try to get them, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `_vvoFields()` function.

You are returning a temporary variable, (this is, a copy), instead of the internal variable.

In order to return the internal variable, modify the function declaration to:

`std::vector<std::vector<Field> >& _vvoFields()`

Note the `&` after the return type.

With this change, you are returning a reference to the internal variable, so any modification to it will update the internal value (since both are the same).

This is different to the original definition, where you where returning a copy of the internal value, this is, a completely different instance.